# Is it possible to change the site from communication to team?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a site that is a communication type and it doesn't allow me to make a quick launch menu on the left. If i had for egzam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to enable quick launch in SharePoint online Communication site?**

This is by the design of Microsoft, in the communication site we cannot have left side (quick launch) navigation.

Reference:

[Communication Site navigation](https://www.wortell.nl/blogs/modern-sharepoint-sites-navigation-options/)

**What is the recommended way to maintain the navigation in modern SharePoint online?**

In the modern SharePoint online, **Megamenu** menu with **hub site** configuration is a long way to go.

For details about hub site and Mega Menu refer to the below article :

[How to create navigation in modern SharePoint Online](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/various-navigation-in-modern-sharepoint-online/)

[Why should we create a hub site in SharePoint Online (benefits of SharePoint hub site)?](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/hub-sites-in-sharepoint-online-modern-site/)

**Can we convert the communication site to the team site?**

As per Microsoft, the answer is **No**.  So, the fastest way to get your content in a team site is - create a team site and migrate your communication site content to it.

Microsoft TechNet reference:

[Communication Site To Team site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/communication-site-to-team-site/m-p/202197)

**How to enable or disable the quick launch menu using the PnP PowerShell in the SharePoint modern team site?**

```
############################Description#######################################################
#The below script will disable the quick launch menu in the SharePoint Online team site.
##############################################################################################
 
CLS
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint2020.sharepoint.com/sites/CustomSearchRND/"
$userName = "Global-sharepoint2020@globalsharepoint2020.onmicrosoft.com"
$passWord = "YourSPOPassword"
$encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord
 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $cred
 
#Getting the site's Web object.
$web = Get-PnPWeb
 
#Disable the Quick Launch Menu
$web.QuickLaunchEnabled = $False
$web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

For details example, refer to the below article :

[How to hide the quick launch menu in SharePoint online using PnP PowerShell?](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/how-to-hide-quick-launch-menu-in-sharepoint-online-using-pnp-powershell/)

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.